# How to convert DStream[(Array[String], Long)] to dataframe in Spark Streaming

Tags: spark-streaming

i am trying to convert my dstream to Dataframe.here is the code that am using to convert my dstream to Dataframe

```
           val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(10))
           val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
           "bootstrap.servers" -> "ffff.dl.uk.fff.com:8002",
           "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
           "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
           "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
           "group.id" -> "1",
           "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
           "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
           )

           val topics = Array("mytopic")
           val from_kafkastream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, 
           String](
           ssc,
           PreferConsistent,
           Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
           )
           val strmk = from_kafkastream.map(record => 
          (record.value,record.timestamp))
          val splitup2 = strmk.map{ case (line1, line2) => 
   (line1.split(","),line2)}

          case class Record(name: String, trQ: String, traW: String,traNS: 
   String, traned: String, tranS: String,transwer: String, trABN: 
  String,kafkatime: Long)

          object SQLContextSingleton {
            @transient  private var instance: SQLContext = _

            def getInstance(sparkContext: SparkContext): SQLContext = {
              if (instance == null) {
                instance = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
              }
              instance
            }
          }
          splitup2.foreachRDD((rdd) => {
          val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext)
          spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
          import sqlContext.implicits._
          val requestsDataFrame = rdd.map(w => Record(w(0).toString, 
  w(1).toString, w(2).toString,w(3).toString, w(4).toString, 
  w(5).toString,w(6).toString, w(7).toString,w(8).toString)).toDF()
          // am getting issue here
          requestsDataFrame.show()
          })
          ssc.start()
```

I am getting error saying following [image]

can someone help how to convert my dstreams to DF as i am new spark world

Comment: All seems a little too complicated. llok at this git example https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/DirectKafkaWordCount.scala.

Comment: its just a word count you provided... do you have solution ?

Comment: No as I am not going to compile it all, but it shows you that it is not that hard. I have the impression you are over-complicating here. If you look at that solution or others, it looks all fairly straightforward. That's my point . I see answer being provided.as well now.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the mistake is when build the Record object because , you don't pass  the kafkatime , only string values, and also is tuple you can't access to the atribute array of this form.

You can try this :

```
import session.sqlContext.implicits._
val requestsDataFrame = rdd.map(w => Record(
  w._1(0).toString,
  w._1(1).toString, w._1(2).toString, w._1(3).toString, w._1.toString,
  w._1(5).toString, w._1(6).toString, w._1(7).toString, w._2))

requestsDataFrame.toDF()
```

Comment: this answer makes sense.. let me try and get back you